# Which database method should I take to collect my monthly information

Tags: mysql

I have information to be collected monthly. same data columns but different content of course. I'm asking about which are the best way to make the user insert this data, should I make a database table for each month with the same columns, or should I make one table with one column to determine the month.

For example:

```
table: July
id|program_name|program_date|program_result

table: June
id|program_name|program_date|program_result
```

Or:

```
table: monthly_info
id|program_name|program_date|program_result|month
```

I'm asking which way is more efficient than the other. 
Thank you

Comment: In general, data that changes dynamically should be in the table contents, not table or column names.

Comment: You can't use table names in join conditions. You will have to rewrite your query to point to a different table for every month.

Comment: Thank you. I got it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create one table to save all your data with date.

```
table: monthly_info
id|program_name|program_date|program_result|date
```

Then you can query monthly data as below.

If your condition month parameter is integer. Use this query. (this will return all data matches to month August)

```
SELECT * FROM monthly_info WHERE MONTH(date) = 8
```

If your condition month parameter is string. Use this query.

```
SELECT * FROM monthly_info WHERE DATENAME(mm, date) = 'August'
```